# Fancybox with Parallax.js not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox, parallax.js

fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/bft7fb6t/

THe parallax image doesn't show up on fancybox launch.  When you resize the output window, the image will appear but it's not in the parallax fashion.  What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.section1').click(function(){
  $.fancybox({
    type: 'inline',
    href: '#fancy-about',
    helpers : {
      overlay : {
        css : {
          'background' : 'blue'
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;  background: transparent;

}
.section1{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:black;
}

#fancy-about{
  display:none;
  color:white;
  width:500px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.js"></script>
<div class="section1"></div>

<div id="fancy-about">
<p>Hey, this is meLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum efficitur sed enim in mollis. Proin molestie libero id congue hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean augue libero, scelerisque id sagittis et, tristique nec ipsum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam congue maximus efficitur. Fusce malesuada, magna eu porttitor fermentum, lorem arcu fermentum mi, porta faucibus lorem mauris sed felis. Curabitur dignissim risus quam, rutrum congue tellus aliquet sit amet. Cras luctus ac lectus non sollicitudin. Sed dolor metus, tempor eleifend orci et, laoreet vulputate orci.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque vitae malesuada massa. Proin facilisis ligula sed turpis scelerisque, ut pellentesque felis pharetra. Praesent metus elit, semper non vehicula non, pharetra quis nunc. Phasellus purus tortor, commodo non eleifend ut, blandit in leo. Aliquam sollicitudin gravida tristique. Nulla convallis nibh id massa eleifend ullamcorper. Morbi ut eleifend nisl, nec tincidunt nunc. Donec facilisis nibh tellus, non scelerisque augue varius elementum. Cras cursus mollis lectus ac malesuada. Nulla bibendum ex malesuada, dignissim neque a, scelerisque ipsum. Etiam pretium gravida odio, ac pulvinar nulla vehicula vel. Vestibulum pellentesque neque purus, eu bibendum ligula euismod id. Cras eu tristique massa. Nunc blandit vulputate mi non maximus.</p>
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/0/0d/025Pikachu.png/250px-025Pikachu.png"></div><p>Hey, this is meLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum efficitur sed enim in mollis. Proin molestie libero id congue hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean augue libero, scelerisque id sagittis et, tristique nec ipsum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam congue maximus efficitur. Fusce malesuada, magna eu porttitor fermentum, lorem arcu fermentum mi, porta faucibus lorem mauris sed felis. Curabitur dignissim risus quam, rutrum congue tellus aliquet sit amet. Cras luctus ac lectus non sollicitudin. Sed dolor metus, tempor eleifend orci et, laoreet vulputate orci.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque vitae malesuada massa. Proin facilisis ligula sed turpis scelerisque, ut pellentesque felis pharetra. Praesent metus elit, semper non vehicula non, pharetra quis nunc. Phasellus purus tortor, commodo non eleifend ut, blandit in leo. Aliquam sollicitudin gravida tristique. Nulla convallis nibh id massa eleifend ullamcorper. Morbi ut eleifend nisl, nec tincidunt nunc. Donec facilisis nibh tellus, non scelerisque augue varius elementum. Cras cursus mollis lectus ac malesuada. Nulla bibendum ex malesuada, dignissim neque a, scelerisque ipsum. Etiam pretium gravida odio, ac pulvinar nulla vehicula vel. Vestibulum pellentesque neque purus, eu bibendum ligula euismod id. Cras eu tristique massa. Nunc blandit vulputate mi non maximus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to include the fancybox CSS file

Comment: thanks for catching that, still can't get my parallax to work though :(